# Installshield: Setting the Installdir to an environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, installshield

EDIT:

NO LONGER RELEVANT.  Due to difficulties with Installshield including not only this issue but also issues with getting it to build with the project in Visual Studio and its inability to replace one of the old files that needs to be replaced I am now coding an installer in C#.  I should have done this earlier because I'd be done by now.  Thank you Christopher Painter and Michael Urman for trying to guide me though this issue.  Unfortunately I did not get anywhere further with it.

ORIGINAL POST BELOW

Honestly, this has been like pulling teeth.  I hope that I'm missing something blatantly obvious.  I have been trying to get Installshield to let me set the INSTALLDIR to an environmental variable.  This is necessary because of the way the company does things.  I know I can set it outside of the installer via a batch file which calls the MSI and passes the folder via an argument, but that solution ended up with an unfriendly MSI.  If anyone has any internal solutions please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer has the Environment table that is exposed by InstallShield in the environment view and component | advanced settings | environment view.

[Setting Environment Variables](http://helpnet.installshield.com/installshield17helplib/IHelpISXSetEnvVariable.htm)

Comment: So if I'm understanding this correctly, you are saying that I need to edit the project in Windows Installer to get to environmental variables?

Comment: InstallShield builds Windows Installer databases.  You edit the project in InstallShield.

Comment: This is even more confusing.  My version of Installshield does not have a menu named component nor do components have a menu named advanced settings.  Is this something I'm allowed to do on the professional version of Installshield or does it require an upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer allows you to refer to environment variables using a variant of property notation. I would suggest [an approach similar to RobertDickau's](http://community.flexerasoftware.com/showthread.php?161649-Getting-Environment-Variable-for-Target-Directory), where you use a set-property custom action early to set `INSTALLDIR` from `[%SOMEVAR]`. Only run the custom action if `INSTALLDIR` isn't already defined, so that people can override `INSTALLDIR` at the command line. Note that this must be run before costing, or you will have to find a different condition and use a set-directory action (like Robert mentions) instead.

Comment: I'll look into custom actions.